# Restore contacts from iCloud to MacBook

Tags: icloud, contacts, restore

How do I restore contacts from iCloud to my MacBook? My contacts groups have disappeared on my MacBook Pro but they are in my iCloud.

What is the process to restore to my Mac?
It is still on my phone but not visible on my Mac

Answer (score 1):

You can also configure iCloud on your Mac to sync your contacts.
Go to `Preferences > Internet Accounts > iCloud` and check `Contacts`. That will restore them to your Mac and keep them in sync with your iOS devices (iPhone in this case), so if you add, delete, or change a contact in any of your devices it will reflect on the rest.

Answer (score 0):

You can export the .vcf from your iCloud account and import them back to the Contacts.app on your computer.

First login to your [icloud.com](https://www.icloud.com/) account.

Navigate to the "Contacts" section.

In the bottom left of your contacts click the gear icon.

Choose "Select All" or whatever contacts you want to export to your computer.

Choose "Export vCard"

This will download a .vcf file.

Double click this downloaded .vcf file and it will open up Contacts.app and ask if you want to import the contacts.

See pictures below for references.

[image: iCloud contacts]

[image: Contacts.app]